# How to subscribe to Page Events in Visual Studio 2008 IDE

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, page-lifecycle

**IMPORTANT** 
**Can any body solve this one ?**
How to create page's Init, Load, PreRender etc. event handlers in VS 2008? When we double click on the page, it will create Page_Load event. How to create othere events of page? I am using c# in ASP.NET application.
[image]
 There is no Event tab in image.

Comment: This is one thing I do like about vb.net. In code view, you can select from a list of all page events to handle that event. Vb.Net has autoeventwireup=false by default. I would like to know a similarily easy way to do with in c#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is your answer
In the solution explorer, right click the page and select "View component designer" from the context menu, now in the properties window you will have the event tab.

Answer (score 3):

For subscribing to Page events there are following ways:

- override the on_xxx methods of the Web.UI.Page class. For ease just start typing `private override` when you will type override keyword the Intellisense will automatically tell you the available methods you can override and you can select it from there and press tab (**The prototype for the method will automatically be created for you**).
- If the page has set **AutoEventWireup** attribute set to true then you can just define a method with prototype and name as `Page_[your event]` like `Page_Init` with appropriate parameters. And the events will will **automatically be wired up**.

  > The ASP.NET page framework supports a mechanism that uses the AutoEventWireup attribute of a Web Forms page to automatically associate page events and event-handler methods. If the AutoEventWireup attribute of the @ Page directive is set to TRUE (or if it is not specified because its default value is TRUE), the ASP.NET page framework automatically calls page event-handler methods.
  >
  > For example, the Page_Init and Page_Load event-handler methods are explicitly called by the ASP.NET page framework, without an explicit event delegate.
  >
  > However, the drawback of using the AutoEventWireup attribute to automatically associate page events and their event-handler methods, is that event-handler methods must have standard, predefined names. This limits how you can name event-handler methods.

---

Following is the summary of page Events in their order:

- PreInit
- Init
- InitComplete
- PreLoad
- Load
- Control events
- LoadComplete
- PreRender
- SaveStateComplete
- Render
- Unload

---

I usually refer this cheetsheet kind of image from MSDN to check which method to override:

[image]

Comment: in case of c# there is no  event tab (That thunder icon)

Comment: who said there isn't i have been using it for years.. you better check it again.. there seems to be some problem with your Visual Studio Installation

Comment: ...are you sure you are accessing it in Design mode and note in Code view

Comment: yes I am accessing it in Design mode, but event tab is not there. Event tab there for controls but for page it is not there. sad :(

Comment: Thanks @ Shekhar_Pro but I want to create these events through VS 2008 IDE. I want VS2008 create prototype for me.

Comment: How is it possible ? its strange

Comment: "How is it possible ?" sorry ask that to Microsoft.. i didn't made the IDE... its simply not there in IDE.. Also i have grown in habit of using the Override method.. so i don't feel like something  is missing.

Answer (score 1):

This link may be helpful -- It is the msdn reference for a pages "life cycle" including creating of other events like you mentioned.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx

In addition to double clicking on page controls (buttons, hyperlinks, datacontrols), there is a drop-down list when looking at the c# file that contains other "life-cycle" events of a page, as well as other control events you have created.

[image]

Comment: sorry, in  drop-down list there are only events that has been created not that has not been created. There is only Page_Load event in drop-down list.

Comment: Exactly there is only Page_Load event only as shown in your posted image, but no Page_Init, Page_PreRender

Answer (score 1):

The way I prefer is to use the On method instead, so type override OnLoad to setup the load event handler, OnPreRender, etc.  Each of these methods essentially calls the respective event handler, as in:

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
   base.OnInit(e); //don't remove
}
```

I also think you can add an event handler manually:

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Without needing to set anything up for this (no explicit listening for the event), but I'm not 100% sure of this.

HTH.

Comment: Thanks @Brian but I want to create these events through VS 2008 IDE. I want VS2008 create prototype for me.

Comment: The option for the events tab would only appear when you open the page up, not select the page from the solution explorer...  try opening the page, click in the designer, and see if there is an events button (lightning bolt).

Comment: I try it but there is sill no event tab  (lightning bolt).

Comment: thats what i answered before but unfortunately it only shows up for controls like button, etc not for page itself

Comment: Then your answer is no.  Only through code.  Page_Load appears when you double-click on it because its setup as the default event (every control can have one [DefaultEvent] attribute definition).

Comment: That lightning bolt option in C# *only* is displayed when the page is in 'Design' view, *not* when viewing the page's source.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6w2tb12s%28v=VS.90%29.aspx (VS 2008 version)

It says that you can create a method declaratively with the name Page_event.

For example, to create a handler for the page's Load event, create a method named Page_Load.

ASP.NET pages automatically bind page events to methods that have the name Page_event. This automatic binding is configured by the AutoEventWireup attribute in the @ Page directive, which is set to true by default. If you set AutoEventWireup to false, the page does not automatically search for methods that use the Page_event naming convention.

Worked for me!